# Existence of a `right' sequence

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Suppose that $f_n: \mathbb{R} \times [0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ is a sequence of bounded variation functions such that there exists $C>0$: $|f_n| < C$ for every $n$ and, as $n \to \infty$, for $t>0$,
\begin{equation} \tag{1}
f_n(\cdot,t) \longrightarrow f(\cdot,t), \quad \text{in } L^1(\mathbb{R}).
\end{equation}
Let $x_n: [0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R} $ be a sequence of absolutely continuous functions that satisfies
\begin{equation} \tag{2}
\frac{d}{dt} x_n(t) = f_n(x_n(t),t), \quad \text{a.e.} - t, \; x_n(0)=0,
\end{equation}
and $x_n(\cdot) \to x(\cdot)$ uniformly in any bounded interval in $[0,\infty)$, for some $x: [0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R} $.

Is the following claim true?

> Claim. For a.e.-$t$, there exists a sequence $y_n$ such that, $y_n \ge x_n (t)$, $y_n \to x(t)$ and 
>   $$f_n(y_n,t) \to f(x(t)+,t),$$
>   where $f(x(t)+,t)$ stands for the right limit in the nomal sense.

**Remark.** This is an attempt to solve a slightly stronger version of [this problem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/339221/the-continuous-convergence-of-f-nx-nt-t-to-fxt-t-given-the-a-e-conv).